# How to compare two text files and anything not matching is filtered out into a new file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a program that comes up with a way to identify the new process ID using two text files.

The first file is going to contain only IDs I want running and the other is going to be the capture all IDs currently running and anything that is included in the first file to be removed and then show me all the process IDs that should not be running.

Then I'm going to stop the process using those IDs.

All I need to know is how to compare those two files and spit out a new file with the process IDs that should not be running.

How would I create this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet. Use the `get-help Compare-Object -Examples` and you will find exactly what you are looking for comparing text files.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the example perimeter.

Comment: `-ShowWindow` parameter is also really useful with the `get-help` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing out the text files and then comparing; what if you tried something like this...

```
$wantedProcesses = @(4,0)
$currentProcesses = Get-Process

$count = 0

do{
    foreach($process in $currentProcesses){
        if($wantedProcesses -contains $process.Id){
        }else{
            Add-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Unmatched.txt" -Value $process.Id
        }
    }
    $count += 1
}until ($count -eq $wantedProcesses.Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Compare-Object`. @erick-guillen mentioned that you can use `help compare-object -examples` to see how that cmdlet is used, or even `help compare-object -full` for all of the details.

Your solution will likely look similar to this, since we are talking about comparing two files:

```
$Wanted = Get-Content wanted.txt | Sort-Object
$Running = Get-Content running.txt | Sort-Object
$Diff = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Wanted -DifferenceObject $Running |
  Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}
).InputObject
```